# client(android) - server(java) communication - local ip address

Tags: android

i am trying to built a client- server communication using RESTful.The client is an android application while the server is a java application. When i call the URL: http://localhost:8888 through my browser i can see the result(it works fine). As i read, using this URL in my client as the endpoint it doesn't work because the localhost is the (emulated)phone. But when i use the local ip of my computer, through the browser i get the message "The connection has timed out" and through the client i can't take any result too. What is wrong with it. What ip I have to use in order to have access to my server?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

127.0.0.1 points back to the android. If you want localhost, give 10.0.2.2 a try.

Here is a little more about the android networking interface:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking

It also has a list of network address spaces.

Comment: Thank you so much! But do you know may why the local ip address doesn't work?

Comment: what do you mean by local ip address?

Comment: my computer's ip (ipconfig -> ip Address)

Comment: I have no idea but it could be a multitude of things.

Comment: If this has been helpful, please consider accepting my answer.